# How can I read keyboard inputs word by word

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here's my problem, I'm writing a program that predict the most probable next word you will type.
So for instance if I just type "you" the program could propose you the word "are".
My problem has nothing to do with this exactly, but it's more on the implementation.
Right now, the only thing I can do is read words until I type enter, and then my program will give me a prediction for the last word of the sentence.
Basically what I would like to do is to stop reading everytime I type a whitespace, then my program respond by the word, and then I could type again another word.
I'm trying to look at the Scanner class, but I don't find anything that could help me here.
Thanks.

Comment: will using delimiters be useful? Please elaborate more on the issue

Comment: How are you reading the input at the moment? Show us some code, so we can work out on how to modify it to your needs.

Comment: Please elaborate as @laish138 has mentioned - the default `Scanner#next()` returns white space delimited tokens (as opposed to `Scanner#nextLine()` which is new line delimited.

Comment: My issues is not really about delimiters I think, basically I want the scanner to stop reading as soon as I type a whitespace, and not after a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You would have to switch the console into raw mode, for which there is no multiplatform solution. You're much better of just making a window with a `TextArea` and using that instead the console window. That can be achieved in very few lines of code.